# WSO2 5.10 SCIM API doesnt send email when creating user with askpassword set to true

Tags: wso2, scim2, wso2-identity-server

I'm testing WSO2 5.10 user creation via SCIM Rest API using the following curl command

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"Smith","givenName":"John"},"userName":"john","password":"password","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"jsmith@test.com","type":"home"},{"value":"jsmith@test.com","type":"work"},{"value":"jsmith@test.com"}],"EnterpriseUser":{askPassword:"true"}}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users
```

It creates a user as expected but doesn't send an email to set up a password. 
However, when an admin tries to create a user through the management console for the same scenario, the user receives an email to set up a password. But not through this API request.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **askPassword** attribute under the `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User` schema as true in the SCIM2 user create request. So try the request as below,

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"Smith","givenName":"John"},"userName":"john","password":"password","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"jsmith@test.com","type":"home"},{"value":"jsmith@test.com","type":"work"},{"value":"jsmith@test.com"}],"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User":{askPassword:"true"}}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users
```

Please refer the official [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/creating-users-using-the-ask-password-option/#ask-password) for more details.

Comment: I tried this request but i received the following error. I also tried the example in the documentation exactly but still got the same error {"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"],"scimType":"invalidSyntax","detail":"Request is unparsable, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","status":"400"}* Closing connection 0

Comment: Did you try with single quotes outside? It worked for me  ex: curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"xx":"xxxxx"}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users

Comment: If still not working better to try with a client such as postman.

Comment: It worked through postman. This seems to be a windows related issue with making curl requests from the command line.